# JS problem: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while passing an object via onClick()

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

My code is like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${model}" var="thread">                       
    <button onclick="getPost(${thread})">
    </button>
</c:forEach>
```

In this part, I want pass an object (thread is an object that get from an ArrayList ${model}), and getPost(object) is a javaScript function. I want make every button to pass the corresponding object to the function and do something, but it shows this strange problem in console

[image]

Comment: what is this framework?

Comment: SpringMVC, model is passed by a controller with the type of the ModelAndView

Comment: `domain.Post@35577a26` is not a valid dot notation, did you miss the quotes? `<button onclick="getPost('${thread}')">`

Comment: I tried this actually, but it causes another problem that the it only passed the string of the object instead fo the object itself

Comment: Then you can't use dot notation, try to change the format of the `${thread}` to `xxx.domain['Post@35577a26']` on the server side

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand what you mean. In the server side, Post is an entity and the controller returns the a list of this kind of entity. What you mean by changing the format?

Comment: It`s actually not the dot notation, xxx.domain is the project path of the Post entity and @35577a26 I think might be the address of this object